# New Widget Families for Lock Screen Widgets in SwiftUI doesn't appear among supported families

Tags: swiftui, widget, ios16, lockscreenwidget

I am trying to code new lock screen widget introduced with ios 16. I follow the steps on the link below, but new supported families of WidgetFamily class (.accessoryInline, .accessoryCircular, .accessoryRectangular) does not appear. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code, first 4 family is supported but the last 3 one don't.

```
@main
struct AppGroupWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = WidgetKind.appGroupWidget1
    var widgetManager = WidgetManager()
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            AppGroupWidgetEntryView(entry: entry).background(Color("WidgetBackground"))
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Steply")
        .description("Widget description")
        .supportedFamilies([
            .systemSmall,
            .systemMedium,
            .systemLarge,
            .systemExtraLarge,
            .accessoryInline,//'WidgetFamily' has no member 'accessoryInline' so this one is not recognized
            .accessoryCircular,//this one also is not recognized
            .accessoryRectangular//this one also is not recognized
        ])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is all about the Xcode version. You have to update your Xcode version to 14.0. And to be able to do this, you should update your macOS to Monterey 12.6